# Find if session is enabled on Azure Service Bus Queue

Tags: c#, azureservicebus

Is there any way to programmatically find (C# or PowerShell) if sessions are enabled on an Azure ServiceBus Queue, given the connection string or QueueClient (or anything else)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus package the following snippet will provide you with what you need:

```
var connectionString = "...";
var client = new ManagementClient(connectionString);
var queueDescription = await client.GetQueueAsync("queue");
Console.WriteLine($"Sessions enabled: {queueDescription.RequiresSession}");
```

Comment: Thanks, I was searching all on QueueClient

Answer (score 1):

You can try this command here [Get-azservicebusqueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.servicebus/get-azservicebusqueue?view=azps-3.0.0). There is a field called RequiresSession that should do the trick (not tested though and the documentation is not definitive).

If the sender of the message does not include the SessionId, and the session is enabled, the message will never reach the client. Being that the case, if you have the session id you can assume that the queue is session enabled. [Message class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.message?view=azure-dotnet)

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar method available in WindowsAzure.ServiceBus to fetch the Queue properties. From there you can check whether the Queue has Session enabled or not.

The method is available in NamespaceManager class.